# Indexer get by reference or get+set?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

This is my class:

```
class MyArray<T>
{
    private T[] data;
    public MyArray(int size)
    {
        data = new T[size];
    }
    public MyArray(in T[] array)
    {
        data = new T[array.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            data[i] = array[i];
    }
    public T this[int i] //I am talking about this indexer
    {
        get => data[i];
        set => data[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Should I, instead of doing like above, define my indexer like this?

```
public ref T this[int i]
{
    get => data[i];
}
```

Which method should I choose? From what I see, method 1 allows you to execute additional code when getting setting the value, however method 2 allows you to do something like `int.TryParse(str, out myArrayObj[i]);`

EDIT: This question doesn't only apply to indexers, but to any property in general.

Comment: I think you've kind of answered your own question. The two methods support different functionalities, which one of them is more important to you?

Comment: You should choose the approach that best suits your needs.

Comment: @Sach Well, `List<T>` doesn't return by reference, however it doesn't execute any additional code when setting elements.

Comment: @DarkAtom I think `List<T>` was created before C# had `ref` returns, so perhaps it would be built different today. There are certainly reasons (auto-vivification, emulate arrays) to wish it did.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the data type (here `int`) is a primitive or a reference type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** If you need a setter then you have to go with regular indexer, because `ref` properties cannot have setters. If setter is not needed then I would always specify `ref` keyword in the indexer/property of **generic** type parameter as they can be value types. It's up to the consumer whether access them by ref or not.

`ref` keyword does not provide any benefit if the type parameter is reference type (a class), but makes a difference for value types, because they can be accessed directly without being copied. So if you want to have access to original values in **your** array, you have to use `ref` keyword. If you want to access value that was in the array, that was passed to `MyArray<T>` class, then you should not copy the values to other private array, because in this case you will get copies of values in private array.

Following examples show how access by ref differs from regular access:

```
[Fact]
public void ArrayTest()
{
    var structs = new[] {new MyStruct()};

    structs[0].Type++;

    ref var @struct = ref structs[0];
    @struct.Type++;

    // Test passes the value was incremented twice, because reference was used.
    structs[0].Type.Should().Be(2);
}

[Fact]
public void MyArrayTest()
{
    var structs = new MyArray<MyStruct>(new[] {new MyStruct()});

    // Compiler error, but was possible in earlier versions of C#
    // and would not modify the item in the array,
    // because value was copied before modification.
    // structs[0].Type++;

    var @struct = structs[0];
    @struct.Type++;

    // Value wasn't incremented, because it was copied on the stack.
    structs[0].Type.Should().Be(0);
}

[Fact]
public void MyRefArrayTest()
{
    var structs = new MyRefArray<MyStruct>(new[] {new MyStruct()});

    structs[0].Type++;

    ref var @struct = ref structs[0];
    @struct.Type++;

    // Test passes the value was incremented twice, because reference was used.
    structs[0].Type.Should().Be(2);
}

struct MyStruct
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
}

class MyArray<T>
{
    private T[] data;

    public MyArray(in T[] array)
    {
        data = new T[array.Length];
        Array.Copy(array, data, array.Length);
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get => data[i];
        set => data[i] = value;
    }
}

class MyRefArray<T>
{
    private T[] data;

    public MyRefArray(in T[] array)
    {
        data = new T[array.Length];
        Array.Copy(array, data, array.Length);
    }

    public ref T this[int i]
    {
        get => ref data[i];

        // Compiler error, ref indexer cannot have setter.
        // set => data[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much by what you intend to do with it, but I would see it from the encapsulation side:

The classic `get` `set` approach is **sturdy and robust**: everyone using your object will go through YOUR rules when getting or setting any value in the object.

With `ref` the situation becomes tricky! You're just giving the reference out and the user of the object can do whatever he/she wants with it. It is like giving away your home keys.

You can't protect yourself against users tampering with your private members:

```
// This might cause several failures or go against the class contract 
// and there is no way to check on the value.
public void AbuseRefProperty() => array.Property = null;
```

The only place I would feel comfortable having a ref property is **in a private inner class**. There you're sure that no one can tamper with it and the parent class is the only one that has full control.

Comment: What about case where my class does not own data, but it is just proxy/wrapper. I want it to be as thin as possible, thus `ref` seems to be number one solution.

Comment: In those rare cases in which a misuses are not possible, `ref` is definitely a good and slimmer choice! It does, though, always break the principle of encapsulation.